# Autorun для CD диска

Tags: windows, автозапуск, cd

Написал программу заставку . Хочу чтоб она запускалась при загрузке CD диска.

И хотелось бы без выбора (открыть проводником или авторан) а сразу чтоб происходил запуск программы прописанной в `Autorun.inf`
В файле прописал так:

```
[autorun]
open=autorun.exe
icon=autorun.ico
```

Сейчас при загрузке выдает окно с выбором действий
Предполагается что диск будет распространяться.

Comment: Насколько я помню, автозапуск отключили еще давно в связи с массовым распространением мальвари через него.

Comment: Дополнение к предыдущему комментарию: отключили еще в windows xp sp2. С тех пор появляется окно с выбором того, что вы хотите сделать с диском. [Статья на википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf)